# Update a specific column if it exists, without failing if it does not

Tags: mysql

I am working with an application which needs to function with any of 300+ different MySQL databases on the same server. The databases all have nearly identical table structures, with slight variations. For example, a particular column might be present in a table for only some of the databases.

I'm wondering if there is a way that, when performing an update on a table, I can update a specific column if it exists, but still successfully execute if the column does not exist.

For example, say I have a basic update statement like this:

```sql
UPDATE some_table
SET col1 = "some value",
    col2 = "another value",
    col3 = "a third value"
WHERE id = 567
```

What can I do to make it so that, if `col3` doesn't actually exist when that query is run, the statement still executes and `col1` and `col2` are still updated with the new values?

I have tried using `IF` and `CASE`, but those seem to only allow changing the *value* based on some condition, not whether or not a column actually gets updated.

I know I can query the database for the existence of the column, then use a simple if condition in the application code use a different query. However, that requires me to query the database twice: once to see if the column exists, and again to actually update it. I'd prefer to do it with one SQL query if possible. I feel like that application code might start to get unwieldy with lots of extra code to check the existence of this-or-that column and conditionally build queries, instead of just having one query which works regardless of which database the application happens to be running against at the time.

To clarify, any given instance of the application is ever only running against one database; there is a different application instance for each database, but the instances will all be running the same code. These are legacy databases that legacy code is also relying on, so I don't want to modify the actual structures in the database to make them more consistent, for fear of breaking the legacy code.

Comment: It's not possible to access columns dynamically in a SQL query. To solve this you need to build the query dynamically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the syntax of your SQL query, including all column identifiers you reference, must be fixed at the time it is parsed, *before* it validates that the columns exist.

A given UPDATE will either succeed fully or fail fully. There is no way to update *some* of the columns if the query fails to update all of them.

You have two choices:

- Query `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` first, to check what columns exist in the table for a given schema. Then format your UPDATE query, including clauses to set each column only if the column exists in that instance of the table.

Or...

- Run several UPDATE statements, one for each column you want to update. Each statement will succeed or fail independently, but you can catch the error and continue on to the remaining statements. You can put all these statements in a transaction, so the set of changes is committed atomically, regardless of how many succeed (a single failed statement does not roll back a transaction).

Either way, it requires you to write more code. That's the unavoidable cost of supporting such variable table structure.

Comment: I see. It's not the answer I had hoped for, but I'm glad you mentioned the thought of running multiple variations of the same query and catching the errors in the application code. That hadn't occurred to me. While not ideal, I think it will probably be a little more readable than querying `information_schema` and conditionally building queries in this situation. That method keeps the complete queries intact.

Comment: Compare with any other programming language. Can you call a function, if you're not sure that function is defined? Sure, but it might be a fatal error you need to catch. Or you can use a feature like _reflection_ to check if the function exists before you call it.

Comment: For sure, that makes sense. Although I must say it would be nice if you could do that reflection in pure SQL without having to bounce back to into application code first.